# Can't see list of web content for Liferay 6.2

Tags: postgresql, liferay

I am using Liferay 6.2 and PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on localhost.

I created basic web contents and tried to display them with the Web Display Content Portlet but the contents do not show up under the setup tab of the portlet.

I also tried making the page a display page by setting up a default Asset Publisher but that too did not help. However, if I add a fresh content to the portlet right on the page it displays on the portlet.

Again, even the contents created on the portlet directly do not show up in the selection list.

I followed the Liferay documentation in all my steps.

Has anyone had this issue before? is there something I am doing wrong or is this a bug in Liferay 6.2?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the scope of your web contents? In which site you created them?

Comment: Can you please add your code here if any?

Comment: As this is not at all programming related, it's a bad fit for stackoverflow. I'd like to suggest asking this on the Liferay Forums at https://www.liferay.com/community/forums

Comment: @Marco Mercuri, i didnt know web contents had scope. Where can i find this please? The scope setting i found is under Contents accordion tab on web content edit page. If i set that to the page where i want the content to show up, it still goes back to Default after i publish the content.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that tried to help on this. I could not resolve it so I uninstalled and reinstalled Liferay but this time I used the hypersonic db that is bundled with it and all works fine now. I don't want to believe this issue came up due to PostgreSQL yet but as soon as i conclude the tutorials i am working on I will try installing on PostgreSQL again and see.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot about this thread. I finally found out that the Web Contents were being created into a wrong site, in my case the Global site. All I had to do is change that to my site at the top left corner of the new content page and contents are then attached to my site and listed.

Comment: This should be edit in original post instead of posting it as answer.Thanks